Where is the mistake in the argument in favor of the (erroneous) claim "every Dedekind cut is a rational cut"?
A cut is a set $C$ such that:
(a) $C\subseteq \mathbb Q $
(b) $C \neq \emptyset $
(c) $C \neq \mathbb {Q} $
(d) for all $a, c \in \mathbb Q $ , if $c\in C$ and $a\lt c$ , then $a\in C $
(e) for all $c\in \mathbb Q$ , if $c\in C$, then there exists $d\gt c$ such that $d\in C$
A rational cut is a cut of the form $C(r) = \{c | c\lt r, r\in \mathbb Q\}$.
I know that the statement "every cut is a rational cut" can be disproved by giving a counterexample. However, I can't prevent myself from finding an air of plausibility to the following argument aiming at justifying that every cut is of the form $C(r)$.

Hence my request: can you please show me where the following argument
goes wrong?

Step 1 :
Suppose $C$ is a cut , and that $C$ is not of the form $C(r)$ for some $r \in \mathbb Q$.
This amounts to saying:
(1) there is no $r$ such that for all $c$ if $c \in C$ then $c\lt r $
(2) implying that: for all $r$  it is not the case that for all $c$ if $c \in C$ then $c\lt r $
(3) implying that:   for all $ r$ there is some $c$ such that $c\in C$  and $c\geq r $
Step 2:
Suppose $r\in \mathbb Q$ and $r\notin C $.
By (3) above there is some $c$ such that: $c\in C$ and $c\geq r$.
Now, if $c=r$ then $r\in C$.
Also, if $c\gt r$ then $ r\lt c$ and, by the "cut" definition,  $r\in C$.
So the hypothesis  $r \notin C$ leads to a contradiction; meaning that $\mathbb  Q\subseteq C$, since $r$ was arbitrary.
Finally we have $C\subset \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq C$, a contradiction (since the first statement negates that all rationals belong to $C$ while the second asserts the same proposition).
The conclusion seems to be that a Dedekind cut that is not a rational cut is not a Dedekind cut; in other words, every Dedekind cut has to be a rational cut.
Note: I can see an objection to the conclusion of "step 2", namely that what the argument shows is that the first conjuction is false, namely $r\in \mathbb Q$. But how to make sense of the negation of this conjunction since the set of rationals is the domain over which range all our number variables (in this argument)?

I think (1) is incorrect. "$C$ is of the form $C(r)$" says more than just "if $c \in C$, then $c < r$" - this second statement is actually "$C \subseteq C(r)$", and this is indeed true for some $r$ for each Dedekind cut.

You wrote $\Bbb C$ when you obviously meant $C$.

@jjagmath  Thanks for pointing this out.

"This amounts to saying:
(1) there is no r
such that for all c if c∈C then c<r"  Not at all!  Take the cut $C={c\in \mathbb Q| c < \pi}$.  That is a cut and it doesn't appear to be a rational cut.  But there certainly exists an $r = 4$ so that if $c \in C$ then $c < \pi < 4 =r$.  What $C$ not being a rational cut means is there is no $r\in Q$ where $c \ge r$ requires that $c \not \in C$.  It certainly DOESN'T mean there is no $r$ greater than all $c\in C$.  All cuts have rational upper bounds.  The just don't all have LEAST rational upper bounds.

A good way of finding the flaw in a "proof" of a statement for which you have a counterexample is to apply the argument to that counterexample and see the first place where you assert something that is false about that counterexample. So, in this case, if $D$ is your counterexample, you would first see whether (1) "there is no $r$ such that for all $c$ if $c \in D$ then $c\lt r $" is true. If it is true, you would then proceed to (2), and so on, until you get to a false statement.

Your argument is wrong right off the bat, as what you claim (1) says is that that the cut $C$ (which is assumed to not be a rational cut) is unbounded (by any rational number, but that is the same as just being unbounded). But that is simply not what not being a rational cut means. Moreover it is easy to see that no cut can be unbounded, as it would easily follow from (d) that every rational number is in the cut, contradicting (c). It is therefore not surprising that you get a contradiction from this start.

(1) in Step 1 contains an error: the "if" in (1) [and (2)] should be "if and only if", which wouldn't allow to conclude (3).
The corrected (3) becomes:

for all $r$, there is some $c$ such that either $c\in C$ and $c\geq r$, or $c\notin C$ and $c<r$.


You're probably right, but can you make it more explicit please? I understand that if weakened  an iff into  an " if then" but fail to see in what sense this is not correct. If the problem pertains to propositional logic, don't hesitate to use propositional symbols to exhibit the erroneous form of my argument

@VinceVickler extended the answer.

colt_browning has given an excellent answer already pinpointing the mistake, but here’s a general tip for finding such mistakes, in places like this where you think you’ve proven something that you know shouldn’t be true in general: Take a counterexample to the general statement, and follow through the proof checking each claim against that counterexample.
Here, for instance, you know that any irrational number should give a counterexample — for instance, the Dedekind cut $D_{\sqrt{2}} = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ x < \sqrt{2} \}$.  Your proof starts with an arbitrary Dedekind cut, which could be $D_{\sqrt{2}}$, and ends up claiming that it’s rational, which $D_{\sqrt{2}}$ is not.   So look at each claim, and check whether it holds for $D_{\sqrt{2}}$.  This may be easier with some statements than others, depending how concrete they are; so you can start anywhere in the middle, with whichever claim seems easiest to check, and if that fails for $D_{\sqrt{2}}$, you know an error has already occurred by that point.
In particular, in your case, I scanned through and (3) — “for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, there is some $c \in C$ with $c \geq r$” — stands out as false, for $D_{\sqrt{2}}$ (and, once one notices this, for any cut) — it says that the cut is unbounded above in the rationals, which certainly isn’t right.  So the error must be before (3) — and checking carefully back, you can come to the specific error colt_browning’s answer points out: that in (1), the characterising property of a rational cut should involve an “if and only if”, not just an “if”.

=== new better answer ====
Being a rational cut of the form $C = \{c| c < r\}$  [assuming our "known universe' is only the rational numbers] means not only that $r$ is an upper bound, but that $r$ is the least upper bound.
Not only does it mean that if $c \in C$ then $c < r$.  It also means that if $c \in C$ then $c \ge r$.  And it also means that if $q < r$ then there is a $c \in C$ so that $q < c$.
$r$ is, of course, not the *only $r > $ all $c \in C$.  After all, if $c \in C$ then $c < r < r+1 < r + 3.5 < r + 17< ....$.  But what is special about $r$ is that if $c \not \in C$ then $c \ge r$.  That is obviously not true for $r+1, r+3.5$ etc. Also if $q < r$ then there is a $c\in C$ so that $q < c < r$.  That is obviously not true for $r+1, r+3.5$ etc.
A cut that isn't rational means that there is no rational $r$ that acts as a least upper bound.  There will always by upper bounds no upper bound will by least.
So you statement 1,2,3 are all incorrect.
They should read:

There is no least $r$ so that if $c \in C, c < r$.  If $c \in C$ implies $c < r$ then there is an $r' < r$ so that if $c \in C$ then $c < r' < r$.

for all $r$ it is not the case that $c \in C \iff c < r$.  For all $r$ there will either be $c\in C$ where $c \ge r$ OR  there will be a  $c < r$ where $c\not \in C$.

for all $r$ there is either a $c \in C$ where $c \ge r$ or there is a $c \not \in C$ were $c < r$.


.... from here on.... your argument just won't work.
=== old answer ====
"Suppose C is a cut , and that C is not of the form C(r) for some r∈Q
.
This amounts to saying:
(1) there is no r
such that for all c if c∈C then c<r"
Being of the form $C= \{c\in \mathbb Q| c < r\}$ means that 1) If $c \in C$ then $c < r$ but it ALSO means 2) If $c \not \in C$ then $c \ge r$.
There will always be an $r$ so that if $c \in C$ then $c < r$.  For example if we are talking about the cut for $\pi$ then if $c \in C$ then $c < 27439827583942798$ and $ 27439827583942798$ is certainly rational.
But $c\not \in $ the cut for $\pi$ does not mean that $c \ge  27439827583942798$. for example $c = 3.5$ is not in the cut for $\pi$ but $3.5 <  27439827583942798$.
What we can say is there is not $r$ where $c\in C \iff c < r$.  For any rational $r$ then either $r < \pi$ or $r > \pi$.  If $r < \pi$ then there are $c \in C$ so that $r < c$.  And if $r > \pi$ there is a $c \not \in C$ so that $c < r$.
From here step 2 "implying that: for all r it is not the case that for all c if c∈C then c<r" needs to be modified to " For all $r\in \mathbb Q$ it is not the case that if $c\in C$ then $c < r$ and if $c \not \in C$ then $c \ge r$".
And 3) need to become "for all $r \in \mathbb Q$ there is either a $c\in C$ where $c \ge r$ OR there is a $c\not \in C$ where $c < r$"
And from there, no contradiction arises.

It seems that identifying $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ as the least upper bound in the case of rational cuts is crucial.  I believe that in Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis (3rd Ed.) Example 1.9 discusses this idea in regards to what essentially is a cut representing $\sqrt{2}$, pointing out that this cut has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}.$

@ad2004 A Deidekind cut is basically a set $D_w= {q\in \mathbb Q| q \le w}$ for some real number $w$.  If $w$ is rational then $w$ is the least upper/maximal element of $D_w$ and is an element of $D_w$.  If $w$ is irrational then $w$ is the least upper bound of $D_w$ but isn't an element of $D_w$.  But of course we can't do that if we haven't defined the reals and the whole POINT of D. cuts is to construct the reals. And the reason we need the reals is the rationals don't have l.u.b prop.
